# Condição dentro de foreach antes de salvar modelo

Tags: cakephp

No meu `Controller` do **CakePHP** foi feito um `foreach` passando todos os dados de um formulário para uma variável.

Agora, como faço para fazer um `if` específico, que seu objetivo seria se o valor que o `foreach` está passando for vazio, passe para o próximo?

```
foreach ($this->request->data['CursoNavigation'] as $indice => $valor) {
    if (empty($valor)) continue;
    // código para continuar e salvar as informações no 'CursoNavigation'
}
```

Comment: Este código parece funcionar. Ocorreu algum problema?

Comment: Eu queria entender uma coisa, cada vez que o foreach roda, essa variável $valor, está com um array diferente?
Se esse código está certo, como faço agora, pra salvar os dados ?

Comment: Para isso preciso saber o que tem dentro de `$this->request->data['CursoNavigation']`, que é a representação dos dados do seu formulário. E além disso, o que exatamente você quer que não esteja vazio para não prosseguir? Algum campo do formulário específico?

Comment: Tenho um formulario que contém 'N' informaçoes, dessas informações, nem todas deverão ser preenchidas, e eu quero que meu controller faça o seguinte, toda vez que ele passar pelo array que contem as informações, ele verifique se está vazia ou não, se caso estiver, ele "pula" essa informação, chegando ao final desse loop, ele salva todas informações.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não quer que determinado campo do seu formulário não seja salvo no banco de dados, mesmo sendo uma *string* vazia, você pode tratar este comportamento no próprio `Model`.

No seu `Model` **CursoNavigation** basta você implementar um *callback* chamado [`beforeSave()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave), que pode ser algo assim:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['campoX'])) {
        unset($this->data[$this->alias]['campoX']);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Ou seja, se no momento que os dados deste `Model` for salvo, o campo `campoX` estiver vazio, então ele será retirado do seu *array* permanecendo um valor nulo no banco de dados.

E o método para salvar no seu `Controller` permanece o mesmo:

```
if ($this->CursoNavigation->save($this->request->data)) {
}
```

Isso vale pra **qualquer momento** que você salvar este `Model`, mas se quiser somente para uma *action* específica, você de fato vai precisar fazer isso diretamente no `Controller`:

```
$data = $this->request->data['CursoNavigation'];

foreach ($data as &$valor) {
    if (empty($valor))
        unset($valor);
}

if ($this->CursoNavigation->save($data)) {
}
```

Comment: Eu ainda preciso pegar um id, de outro model, na minha tabela existe uma coluna chamada `curso_id` que salva esse valor.
Então meu código ficou assim, mas ele dá um erro na hora de salvar, fiz alguma coisa errada?
        `$this->Curso->create();
            foreach($this->request->data['CursoNavigation'] as $valor ){
                if(empty($valor)) continue;
                $valor['curso_id'] = $this->Curso->id;
                $this->CursoNavigation->create();
                $this->CursoNavigation->save($valor);
            }`

Comment: É sempre bom você nos dar um exemplo completo, assim fica mais claro a sua dúvida. Você pode [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/58842/edit) sua pergunta e acrescentar todas estas informações. Com este seu comentário, eu já passei a não entender exatamente.